# Gradle Tooling API not being resolved

Tags: maven, gradle, jboss-arquillian

I have the `Gradle Tooling API` as a dependency for Arquillian Tests that I am writing.

I am trying to figure out the best way to pull it in.

Here's what I've tried:

In my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile 'org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:1.10'
    ...   
}
```

This did not bring down the dependency.

I also went to search for it on Maven Central and could not find any matches.

I went to my local Gradle install: `C:\gradle\gradle-1.10\lib` and I do see `gradle-tooling-api-1.10.jar`.

I guess I could copy that into my project, but that *feels* wrong.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/make_the_tooling_api_available_on_maven_central

or you can find it in Bintray's JCenter repository (add `jcenter()` to `repositories` block).

Answer (score -1):

Please Upgrade Gradle plugin from Older version to newer version, How to Upgrade Tooling API

> Eclipse--> Help--> Eclipse Market place --> Search

For Gradle and upgrade to the latest version by doing like above